# Which is costlier "rename" or "link and unlink" in C

Tags: c, linux

I have about 100,000 files in a directory. I have to move all these files to another directory. There are two ways of doing it.

1. `rename(oldfile, newfile)`
2. `link(oldfile, newfile)`
    `unlink(oldfile)`

Which approach is better? Are there any other better solutions?

Comment: `rename(oldfile, newfile)` = one call

Comment: I replaced "lacs" with 100,000, assuming it was a reference to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh which is really not used in English as far as I know. I'm not a native English speaker so I might be wrong; anyway I think a number is more easily understood.

Comment: @unwind, thanks I had some trouble understanding this sentence :)

Comment: Is this for a "one off" or something you have to do regularly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer:

The first solution.

---

Using the `rename` call you only execute one system call, and it can be further optimized by the system and / or the implementation.
You also state clearly what you intend to do, which is more important than simply searching ultimate performance on a single point of your program.

The `link`/`unlink` solution works also, but it's really not clear what you intend to do.
Also, how do you manage the `link` on multiple filesystems ? And the link is not even possible on some filesystem or operating system.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rename()`.

Not all filesystems support having multiple links to files, and you can't have multiple links to a directory at all. `rename()`, on the other hand, always works.